# What is Fair Play Award?

Tags: cricket, tournaments, awards, indian-premier-league

> *Fair Play awards are given every year in IPL.*

**Generally,**

- What is Fair Play award?
- Other than Cricket, in which sport is this award given?

**In Cricket,**

- Is this award given in any other tournament than IPL?
- How are the points for this award calculated ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fairplay awards are given out during each IPL year. It is sponsored by Vijay Mallya's Kingfisher brand and therefore branded as Kingfisher Fair play Awards. Chennai Superkings lead the tally in winning this the most times with three awards. Kings XI Punjab and Rajasthan Royals have won it once each and as of now, Rajasthan Royals are leading the table for this award in the current year. Points are given out by the umpires at the end of each game depending on how they perceive each team has behaved on the field. The team with the most points at the end of the group stage wins this Kingfisher Fairplay award.

Football too has fairplay awards but I am not sure how they work.

In cricket, only IPL gives out this fairplay award. Players do not care much about these awards and are more focussed on winning the IPL than this side award. So this award has very less significance and is basically to get sponsorship more than anything else.

Answer (score 2):

The IPL Fair play awards are the awards presented to the teams to encourage the players,playing the IPL, to play with the right spirit. Players often tend to be aggresive and would also sometimes go to any extent to get their way with the umpires. To discourage this attitude of the players and build the comradarie between the players of different teams, this intiative was introduced in IPL. The umpires rate the team after the match. They can give maximum of ten points.

Quote from wikipedia on how points are awarded.

> A team can be awarded a total of ten points per match, out of which
>   four points are given on the basis of how the team has adhered to the
>   "spirit of the game" in the opinion of the umpires. The other three
>   criteria are based on the respect towards to the opposition, the laws
>   of cricket and the umpires.

By the looks of it, it is obvious that it is purely dependent on the umpires. 
I do not think it is awarded in any other tournaments or sports.